# RequireJS not loading module properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, wamp

I'm experiencing a weird issue with RequireJS. I had never used it before, so bear with me please.

I have a WAMP server running with my webpage. Now, when I test the page *without* using WAMP (just opening the html file on the browser), everything works fine:

Result: (See console log)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHZ74.png

When I load the file using WAMP, my module seem to not be loaded.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIkH7.jpg

Here are the scripts:

main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jQuery": "jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min",
        "jQueryUI": "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "jQueryUI": {
            export:"$" ,
            deps: ['jQuery']
        }
    }
});
alert("hello"); // This is always displayed
require(["app"], function(App){
    App.initialize();
});
```

app.js

```
define(["jQuery", "jQueryUI"], function(Init){
    var initialize = function () {
        console.log("----------[Initialize]----------"); //DEBUG
        console.log("----------[   TABS   ]----------"); //DEBUG
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        console.log("----------[   MENU   ]----------"); //DEBUG
        $( "#selectmenu" ).selectmenu();
    };

    return {
        initialize : initialize
    };
});
```

Why is this even happening? It is also weird that, even though there's nothing on the console, the Tabs seem to be initialized properly while the Select Menu is not...

Comment: @Louis How is this a duplicate? I'm sorry but I dont see how this is a case of RequireJS being case sensitive. Even is I change it all to lowercase, the issue persists.

Comment: You require `jquery` as `jQuery` which is definitely wrong, as explained in the other question.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the source of the problem I am having. Therefore, this is not a duplicate.